# Beautiful soup extraction of text within span tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text `Weight: 16.5 pounds` from the following HTML:

```html
<div class="product__description__text">.........
<p dir="ltr"><span><strong>Dimensions:</strong> 39 x 17.3 x 32.2 inches</span></p><p dir="ltr"><span><strong>Weight:</strong> 16.5 pounds</span></p><p dir="ltr"><span><strong>Weight limit:</strong> 35 pounds</span></p><p dir="ltr"><span><strong>Height limit:</strong>&nbsp;32 inches</span></p></div>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```py
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product'})
Weight_L = []
for result in results:
    if result.find('p', attrs={'dir':'ltr'})is not None:
        weight = result.span.text
    Weight_L.append(weight)
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only finding `weight`, I would suggest you to only check if the keyword "weight" is in the `p` tag. Also, if you use `find`, it would only return the first result - so if the first `p` tag is not "Weight", you would not be able to find it.
Also, if your class name is `product__description__text`, you should also change your finding class name to `product__description__text`.

```py
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product__description__text'})
Weight_L = []
for result in results:
    p_tags = result.find_all('p', attrs={'dir':'ltr'})
    for tag in p_tags:
        if "Weight:" in tag.text:
            weight = tag.text
            Weight_L.append(weight)
```

If the above code you posted is `soup`, the result would be: `['Weight: 16.5 pounds']`

Answer (score 0):

The `Weight: 16.5 pounds` is in second `p` tags from parent class `.product__description__text`, you can get second `p` using `p:nth-child(2)`

```
results = soup.select(".product__description__text p:nth-child(2)")
Weight_L = []
for result in results:
  Weight_L.append(result.text)
  print(result.text)
```